# Css form with two div<> inside

Tags: css

I have 2 div<> that I would like to be next to eachother.  They are inside of a form<>.  The one I have on the left won't float all the way up.  It seems that my First Div keeps blocking it.  I have resized it multiple times and It still doesn't work.  Here is my Css code and as you can see there is not much to it.  I also have no inline styling.  My first Div is called ContactInput and my second Div is called invisible

```
 #body {            
       border: 1px double black;
       } 

 #checkout {                    //this is just a head at the top
     text-align:left;
     border-bottom: 1px solid black;
     }
 #contactInput{
    clear:right;
    padding:.5em;

   }

 #invisible{
   float:right;
   padding:.5em;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```css
#contact {
  width: 50%;
  padding:.5em;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#invisible {
  width: 50%;
  padding:.5em;
  background: red;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="contact">
</div>
<div id="invisible">
</div>
```

I recommend `flex` instead of `float`

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}
#contact {
  flex: 1;
  padding:.5em;
  background: blue;
}
#invisible {
  flex: 1;
  padding:.5em;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div id="contact">
  </div>
  <div id="invisible">
  </div>
</div>
```